# Übersetzung von "hit" im Sinne von Autounfällen

Tags: single-word-request

Wie kann man kurz und treffend auf Deutsch sagen:

> **His car hit mine** (at full speed, suddenly, with much impact etc.).

Meine Ideen wären jetzt:

> Sein Auto ist in meins reingefahren / meinem aufgefahren.
>
> Sein Auto ist mit meinem zusammengestoßen.

Aber das ist zu lang und klingt mir zu wenig nach Krach.

Bessere Vorschläge?

Comment: "gerammt" (comments must be 15 characters)

Comment: @KilianFoth, der ist gut! Allerdings ist "rammen" ein relativ leichter Unfall oder? Ich würde daraus nicht unbedingt einen Totalschaden schließen. Deswegen suchen wir nach weiteren Alternativen :)

Comment: Nein, _rammen_ ist definitiv nicht leicht (vielleicht meintest Du _schrammen_?)

Comment: warum sollte "rammen" nur für einen leichten Unfall stehen?

Comment: Weil ich das Wort so verinnerlicht habe; ich lasse mich gern eines besseren Belehren, falls ich damit falsch lag. Möglicherweise habe ich das mit **schrammen** verwechselt, ja.

Comment: @BarthZalewski "Dampframme", "Rammbock", ...

Comment: Rammen klingt für mich eher, als ob das Auto mit einem Panzer kollidiert wäre ;) Oder bei einer Verfolgungsjagd von der Straße abgedruckt wurde. Zu einem gewissen Grad steckt da wohl auch immer Absicht dahinter.

Comment: Dann muss ich wohl meine abgespeicherte Bedeutung von "rammen" revidieren :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Häufige **umgangssprachliche** Wendungen bemühen sich des Lärms, der bei einem Zusammenstoß entsteht:

> Sein Auto ist in mich reingekracht.
>   Sein Auto ist auf meins drauf gekracht.
>   Er ist auf mich draufgeknallt.

Comment: Das gefällt mir sehr gut, weil es eben so schön nach Bums klingt. +1

Comment: @BarthZalewski Aber es ist halt leider nur Umgangssprache ;)

Comment: Umgangssprache ist gut, die benutzt man ja schließlich am meisten :)

Comment: +1 für "reinkrachen". Das Wort erster Wahl. Nicht zuletzt weil OPs Satz "His car hit mine" eindeutig Umgangssprache ist.

Comment: Ich habe mich jetzt entschieden, diese Antwort zu akzeptieren, weil sie genau das liefert, wonach ich gesucht habe.

Comment: Die Verben sind gut, aber ich hab' irgendwie das Gefühl, dass man in Deutsch nicht "sein Auto" sagen würde sondern "er"

Comment: @Emanuel: genau - das habe ich kurz versucht in den drei Beispielen zu variieren (Auto = er/mich, drauf/rein, beliebig austauschbar) ohne näher darauf einzugehen, da ja nicht Thema der Frage.

Comment: @Loong: danke für den Edit, *reinkrachen* gibt es, *draufkrachen* eher nicht (auch wenn man in der Umgangssprache natürlich alles machen daf).

Comment: @Takkat: Ja, ich habe mir auch überlegt, dass es *draufkrachen* eigentlich nicht gibt. Allerdings gibt es *[draufknallen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/draufknallen)* und *[draufbrummen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/draufbrummen)* sowie einige andere analog gebildete Verben mit *drauf,* die zusammengeschrieben werden.

Comment: @Loong: auch wieder wahr - mit draufknallen wäre auch eine Variante gemacht, ich editiere das mal so.

Answer (score 4):

Dein Vorschlag mit "zusammenstoßen" passt eigentlich recht gut.

"auffahren" verwendet man nur, wenn jemand von hinten auffährt, also passt das nicht auf alle Unfälle. Ein gutes Wort für einen Unfall, bei dem beide Fahrzeuge aufeinander zufuhren, ist: "Frontalzusammenstoß".

"reingefahren" ist eher umgangssprachlich. Wenn du von einem Unfall erzählst, ist das keineswegs falsch. (z. B. der Polizei, weil du den Unfall gesehen hast)

Als Alternative geht auch das in den Kommentaren genannte "rammen".

Answer (score 3):

Zwar nicht urgermanisch, aber ein etabliertes Fremdwort:

> Kollidieren

gegebenfalls mit "ungebremst" oder "in voller Fahrt" zu kombinieren.

Answer (score 1):

*Rammen* wurde schon genannt, *touchieren* wäre möglich (das ist in der Tat eher leicht), ugs.: ist mir reingefahren, hat mich abgeschossen